# Trying to make a "server" for flashdrives and HDDs. Using lubuntu, open for changing Distros

Tags: networking, lubuntu, webserver, lan, shared-folders

Good moment everyone, I'm trying to make a network shared folder for all my flashdrives and HDD's. It would be something like, when anyone plugs a new device it would show on all pcs in lan, so anyone can access.

Does anyone have any kind of ideas where to start?
PS: I'm using Lubuntu,because its a Live USB, but I can install other Distro.

Comment: There is no implementation of this in Ubuntu such that for any USB plugged into any network device it would be globally usable.  There may be methods to implement but they are NOT easy nor the best approach from a security perspective.

Comment: This *could* be achieved on one central server with correct mount options, etc. and have it shared from that one server to all other systems by mounting a root file share folder but that is not easy nor very secure either

Comment: security isn't a worry where I want to do this, only one pc have access to the internet and itt isn't on the lan i'm trying to do it.